# SSIS (C# or VB): delete rows 1-12 in all excel files in directory

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

Before importing data from multiple excel files I need to get rid of first 12 rows in each worksheet. I am going to use [the code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-RENjpYfc0fX3RhZkx2X2FjQnM/view) from [this solution](http://www.techbrothersit.com/2016/03/how-to-load-excel-file-name-and-sheet.html) for bulk processing script task.

**Questions:**

- What code should I insert into the script to delete rows? (I suppose right after `//Load the DataTable with Sheet Data so we can get the column header`); or
- How to modify this code to make it read excel files starting from Row 13; or,  alternatively
- What SSIS task should I insert before the script for bulk row deletion?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (with the code in the question rather than on a separate site).

Comment: Thanks @mjwills for your feedback. However, to meet these requirements I need at least to understand the code, while I don't.

Comment: For excel you can name ranges like this: Select * from [SheetName$A13:P]

Comment: Thanks @KeithL ! However, I have absolute zero knowledge of C# :( If you kindly advise what and where to put into the code, that would be great.

Comment: Are all the sheets the same format?

Comment: Hi @KeithL, 
Yes, they all have the same format. Each file contains only one tab. Tab names are different though - that's why I found the referred code useful.

Comment: You can do this mostly outside of c#. I'll forward you something later. But I mean time. You should develop 1 sheet with everything hard coded.

Comment: Great thanks @KeithL !!!! You are a legend! I highly appreciate you effort and time you spent to help me. Will try right now.

Comment: Hi @KeithL, what connection string should I put into **connstring2** variable? There are plenty of them in https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2010/ , but none worked for me so far.

Comment: @Mchief  -- Added info about connection strings to my answer. The site mentioned is extremely useful with figuring out connection strings. You may have to install the ACE driver, but that is another issue entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a method for looping through sheets:

Create a data flow task to read sheet names into ADO object.

[image: Data flow]

First item is a script component as a source.
I have a variable for connection string to the Excel Spreadsheet

[image: connstr]

Created an Output of SheetName

[image: Output Setup]

Here's the code to read tab names:
[image: C#]

You are basically opening the spreadsheet with oleDB.
Putting the table names into a data table

Looping through the data table and writing out the rows to output.

Make sure to close the Connection!!! This may cause errors later if you don't.

The next step is a conditional split as for some reason the result has duplicates of tab names and they all end in an '_'.

[image: Conditional Split]

Next step is deriving a column to clean the sheet name of exta "'"

[image: DerivedCol]

Create a Variable of type Object: I named mine ADO_Sheets

Insert a recordset destination object:
1. Set the variable to the variable you just created
2. Map the columns for clean Sheet

Now back to the Control Flow and set up a foreach loop control:
[image]

Configure the foreach...
Enumerator: Foreach ADO Enumerator
Source: ADO_Sheets
Variable Mapping: Set to a variable called SheetName

I have a Function Task inside the loop but it is more for ease of understanding, it could have been down in the variables:
[image: SQL]

This variable is now your select for extracting the data off that page.

Last is the data flow task you want to run.

**Lot's of work, but I use this so often I thought I would share!!!**

**Adding info about connection strings to Excel (xlsx)**

Excel 2010
Xlsx files
Connect to Excel 2007 (and later) files with the Xlsx file extension. That is the Office Open XML format with macros disabled.

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";

"HDR=Yes;" indicates that the first row contains columnnames, not data. "HDR=No;" indicates the opposite.

Source: https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/

Comment: I stole this from another answer I provided in the past. For your example on starting on 13th row, I would change the expression to "SELECT * FROM [" + @[User::SheetName] + "$A13:P]"     Where P signifies your width.